# Avoid Having Duplicate Email Everytime Googlesheet is edited by Users (Google Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am new in javascript and still learning. I had made a Spread Sheet as a tracker of work data with multiple users working on it. WorkArea tab[WorkArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrjDE.png) is where we tag the time and if completed. Another tab is the Error Tab [ErrorTAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96gqm.png) is a query tab and shows envelope number if tagged incorrectly (no time input and was tagged completed). In the error tab there is a counta formula on cell "S3" which will determine if there an error and will show "TRUE". My problem is that my code is sending too many emails every time users make an edit. If possible, I want it to send email once. Can you help me on this?

Here is the code I made with onEdit trigger

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var errorTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Error');
  var cellRef = errorTab.getRange('S3').getValue();
  var dataRef = "Kindly Check " +  errorTab.getRange('B3').getValue() +  errorTab.getRange('H3').getValue() + errorTab.getRange('N3').getValue();
  var oldValue  = sp.getProperty('S3') || 0;

  if(cellRef == false && cellRef == oldValue) return;
  else 
  var option = {
    cc: "admin1@gmail.com",
  }
  {GmailApp.sendEmail("admin@gmail.com",
  "Dating Contracts Email Notification for Error Tab",
   dataRef,option);
   sp.getProperty('S3', cellRef);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My problem is that my code is sending too many emails every time users make an edit. If possible, I want it to send email once.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: There 11 users in the sheet. In the error tab, once the condition is met S3 will show True which will trigger the code. My goal is to prevent the code from sending too many emails, I want it ro send 1 email only once conditon is met. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your current script, when the cell "S3" of "Error" sheet is `TRUE`, `GmailApp.sendEmail` is run. In your goal, after the email was sent, even when the cell "S3" of "Error" sheet is `TRUE`, you don't want to send the email. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes you got it right. I want it to send 1 email only. This is just to notify admin that there was an incorrect tagging.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about putting `sent` to the column "T" and checking it? By this, after an email was sent, the next email is not sent by checking `sent` at the column "T". And also, you can see it as the status by the browser. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I dont have an idea how to do that. Can you help me on how will i put that into code? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. Before I modify your script, I have a confirmation point. In your script, the cell "S3" is used. In your actual situation, only this cell is used? For example, the cells of "S4", "S5",,, are used?

Comment: The S3 contains =COUNTA(A3:R10) >0, maybe i could try your idea of having it per row like A3:R3, B4:R4 and so on.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, in that case, when `sent` is put to the column "T", no email is sent. I thought that this situation might not the goal you expect. So, I think that it is required to think of another method. But I cannot understand your actual situation. So I cannot think of it soon. I apologize for this.

Comment: I think you got mixed up my apology. I want your idea that if email sent it will show sent on T. Can you help me recode this? thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I want your idea that if the email sent it will show sent on T. Can you help me recode this?`, I post the modified script for achieving it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? But, as I have already mentioned in my previous comment, in this case, after an email was sent, the email cannot be sent. Please be careful about this. When you want to send the email again, please remove the value of cell "T3". By this, the email can be sent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try this later and update you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. When that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following replying,

> I want your idea that if email sent it will show sent on T.

when you want to put `sent` to the column "T" (in your situation, the cell "T3") after the email is sent, how about the following modification?

By the way, I think that `sp.getProperty('S3', cellRef);` occurs an error. Because `getProperty` is only one argument. I thought that you might have wanted to be `sp.setProperty('S3', cellRef);`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var errorTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Error');
  var [cellRef, sent] = errorTab.getRange('S3:T3').getValues()[0];
  if (sent == "sent") return;
  var [b3,,,,,,h3,,,,,,n3] = errorTab.getRange('B3:N3').getValues()[0];
  var dataRef = "Kindly Check " + b3 + h3 + n3;
  var oldValue = sp.getProperty('S3') || 0;
  if (cellRef == false && cellRef == oldValue) return;
  var option = { cc: "admin1@gmail.com" }
  GmailApp.sendEmail("admin@gmail.com", "Dating Contracts Email Notification for Error Tab", dataRef, option);
  errorTab.getRange("T3").setValue("sent")
  sp.setProperty('S3', cellRef);
}
```

Comment: Yes youre right a mistake on my end. it should be setProperty. Thank you for correcting that.

Comment: Here is the problem I encountered, even if the values on b3, h3, n3 are blank it always shows "sent" in t3 which stops the code from sending email when a values shows on b3, h3, n3

Comment: @Mr. Explorer Thank you for replying. About `even if the values on b3, h3, n3 are blank it always shows "sent" in t3 which stops the code from sending email when a values shows on b3, h3, n3`, you don't want to send the email when the cells "b3, h3, n3" are empty. Is my understanding correct? From your question and your script, I couldn't understand it. So, at first, I would like to confirm whether my understanding is correct. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Hello Tanaike! Sorry for the late revert on this. The Idea and the code you gave works fine now, I just excluded the set/getPropreties and it worked well. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Mr. Explorer Thank you, too.